# Limit characters in product name attribute while adding a new product in Magento Admin Panel with a hint?

Tags: product, catalog, admin-panel

Is there a way to limit the characters that can be entered in Magento Admin Panel while adding a new product? Please see the image below to understand the issue clearly. Also, provide a hint (doesn't have to exactly be like below, could be a js alert or anything) as long as it limits the user to enter furthermore characters?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use prototype.js for this, since you already have access to the library in the back end.

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15809872/add-a-character-count-to-admin-inputs-and-textareas

An alternative:

Something like this would work, just get the script added in the admin product pages and point to the field you're wanting to count:

```
/* Counter Script
 * Requires Prototype Library
 * By: <stuff@milkfarmproductions.com>
 * http://milkfarmproductions.com
 * This work is licensed under the Creative Commons Attribution-Share Alike 3.0
 * http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/us/
 *
 * Requirements:
 * - A 'texter' input field, the field to be counted
 * - A 'counter' input field with class equal to 'countClass' variable, the field to contain the count
 * - Set id of 'counter' to <TEXTER_ID> + '_count'
 * - Set initial value of 'counter' input field to maximum allowable characters (integer) of 'texter'
 *
 * Recommendations:
 * - Set 'counter' input field to disabled
 *
 * Note:
 * - This script can handle multiple 'texter/counter' pairs on the same page
 * - 'truncate' variable controls whether or not 'texter' is truncated if 'max' is exceeded
 */

var countClass = 'text-count';
var truncate = false;

var Counter = Class.create({

    initialize: function(text_id, count_id, truncate) {
        if(!$(text_id)) throw("Attempted to initalize counter with text id: " + text_id + " which was not found.");
        if(!$(count_id)) throw("Attempted to initalize counter with count id: " + count_id + " which was not found.");
        this.texter = $(text_id);
        this.counter = $(count_id);
        this.max = this.counter.value;
        this.truncate = truncate;
        this.updateCounter();
        var keyHandler = this.keyHandler.bindAsEventListener(this);
        this.texter.observe('keyup', keyHandler);
        this.texter.observe('keydown', keyHandler);
    },

    updateCounter: function(el) {
      this.counter.value = this.max - this.texter.value.length;
    },

    truncateTexter: function(el) {
      this.texter.value = this.texter.value.substring(0, this.max);
    },

    keyHandler: function(e) {
      if (this.truncate && this.texter.value.length > this.max) {
        this.truncateTexter();
      } else {
        this.updateCounter();
      }
    }

});

document.observe("dom:loaded", function(){
  count_els = $$('input.' + countClass);
  for (var i = 0; i < count_els.length; i++) {
    var count_id = count_els[i].id;
    var text_id = count_id.replace(/_count$/, '');
    new Counter(text_id, count_id, truncate);
  }
})
```

- https://gist.github.com/milkfarm/1926711

---

Normally you would add it via a Layout handler

```
<adminhtml_catalog_product_edit>
    <reference name="head">
        <action method="addJs"><script>your_js_file.js</script></action>
    </reference>
</adminhtml_catalog_product_edit>
```

Comment: Hey Boomer, thanks for your answer. +1 for this. Look below. You put same answer twice. Remove the below one :)

Comment: @B00MER This looks very promising. But, I have a question - Where exactly would I put the script and how :(

Comment: @NavikGoswami see addition to answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can try creating a custom extension using below code. 
 
**app/code/local/Custom/CharacterCount/etc/config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<config>
    <modules>
        <Custom_CharacterCount>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Custom_CharacterCount>
    </modules>
    <global>
    <models>
            <characterCount>
                <class>Custom_CharacterCount_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>characterCount_mysql4</resourceModel>
            </characterCount>
            <characterCount_mysql4>
                <class>Custom_CharacterCount_Model_Mysql4</class>
            </characterCount_mysql4>
        </models>
        <resources>
            <characterCount_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Custom_CharacterCount</module>
            <class>Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Setup</class>
                </setup>
        <connection>
                    <use>core_setup</use>
                </connection>
            </characterCount_setup>
        <characterCount_write>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_write</use>
                </connection>
            </characterCount_write>
            <characterCount_read>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_read</use>
                </connection>
            </characterCount_read>
        </resources>
    </global>
    <adminhtml>
        <layout>
        <updates>
            <characterCount>
                <file>characterCount.xml</file>
            </characterCount>
        </updates>
        </layout>
    </adminhtml>
</config>
```

**app/code/local/Custom/CharacterCount/sql/characterCount_setup/mysql4-install-1.0.0.php**

```
<?php
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();

$this->updateAttribute(
    Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::ENTITY,
    'name',
    array(
        'frontend_class' => 'validate-length maximum-length-80'
    )
);

$installer->endSetup();
```

**app/code/local/Custom/CharacterCount/Model/Mysql4/CharacterCount.php**

```
<?php

class Custom_CharacterCount_Model_Mysql4_CharacterCount extends Mage_Core_Model_Mysql4_Abstract {

}
```

**app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/characterCount.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout>
    <adminhtml_catalog_product_edit>
        <reference name="head">
        <action method="addJs"><script>characterCount.js</script></action>
        </reference>
    </adminhtml_catalog_product_edit>
    <adminhtml_catalog_product_new>
        <reference name="head">
        <action method="addJs"><script>characterCount.js</script></action>
        </reference>
    </adminhtml_catalog_product_new>
</layout>
```

**js/characterCount.js**

```
Event.observe(window, 'load', function() {

    Element.insert( $('name'), { 
        'after': "<div id='name_counter'>Character Left: <span id='name_counter_num'>"+(80-$('name').getValue().length)+"</span></div>"
    });

    Event.observe('name', 'keyup', function(event) {  
        $counter = 80-$('name').getValue().length;
        $("name_counter_num").update($counter);
    });

    $("name_counter").setStyle({ color: 'red' });

    document.getElementById("name").setAttribute("maxlength", "80");
    document.getElementById("name").setAttribute("length", "80");

});
```

**app/etc/modules/Custom_CharacterCount.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config>
    <modules>
        <Custom_CharacterCount>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Custom_CharacterCount>
    </modules>
</config>
```